# Images Clear on Windows but Fuzzy on Mac

Tags: images, windows, mac, resolution

So I have a website and it has a carousel on one of the sidebars. On windows, the pictures that flip through are crisp and clear, but I looked at them on a Mac and they're all fuzzy. Does this have to do with the resolution of a Mac v. the resolution of my Windows laptop, or is it something else?

Answer (score 2):

Your Mac is probably retina, which means it uses twice the amount of pixels to display things.

Some articles with more information:

- http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/05/supporting-apple-retina-displays-on-web.html
- http://www.leemunroe.com/designing-for-high-resolution-retina-displays/

You can emulate retina displays on Windows in [Firefox by changing the pixel ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17228146/1419007). This should replicate the problem you are seeing on the Mac but this time within Windows.